# Using an inline formset in generic update view for editing related objects via a foreign key

Tags: django, inline-formset

It's clear from the django docs how [to use an inline formset in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

But what if, following an example in the docs, you'd like to edit books related to an author via an Authors generic update view.

Is there a better or alternative approach to the following:

1. Create additional formset and add it to a context in get_context_data() method of a generic update view.
2. Deal with this additional formset in a form_valid() method of a generic update view - check if it's valid and save or update the context and return back if it's not.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(AuthorUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        BooksFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields='__all__', extra=1)

        if self.request.POST:
            # Create a formset instance to edit an existing model object,
            # but use POST data to populate the formset.
            data['books'] = BooksFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.get_object())
        else:
            # Create a formset with the data from model object and add it to context
            data['books'] = BooksFormSet(instance=self.get_object())
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        books = context['books']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if books.is_valid():
                books.instance = self.object
                books.save()
            else:
                context.update({'books': books})
                return self.render_to_response(context)

        return super(AuthorUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```